# Dirichlet series summation method

Tags: limits, summation, divergent-series

Is it true that if

$\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...=C$ exists

then it is necessarily true that

$\lim\limits_{s\to0}\frac{a_1}{1^s}+\frac{a_2}{2^s}+\frac{a_3}{3^s}+... =C$

It seems like it must be true but I am not sure and don't want to make any assumptions that it is. It looks very similar to Zeta function regularization but ZFR concerns sums in the form

$\frac{1}{a_1^s}+\frac{1}{a_2^s}+\frac{1}{a_3^s}+...$ Which is quite different to my series.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19410/do-abel-summation-and-zeta-summation-always-coincide .